# Is it possible to change CssClass via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, class

On Page_Load, I use CssClass to change the classes of TableCells in C#. Then I use Javascript to change the classes of the corresponding  elements. This doesn't change the value of CssClass for the TableCells though.

How can I get the new Classes in C# after changing them with javascript?

Comment: you cannot. since the postback reverves  any changes made by JavaScript

Comment: You could set a flag (via a hidden field) and then look at that flag on the server to determine what to set the `CssClass` property to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side changes don't affect controls when posting back to the server because the control's state is stored on the ViewState. A possible work-around is using a hidden field to store the CssClass value client-side and then manually update your table cells on the server from this hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use server side attributes to track client side state. If that is the case, you should rethink this approach and use a different mechanism to track state b/w client and server (like hidden fields).